# Jpeg File Zipping does not compress at all

Tags: compression, 7-zip, jpeg, winrar

i'm trying to compress some jpeg photos, the total dimension is around 150MB, but when i try to zip it using the maximum compressing rate, i keep getting something around 150MB.

I tried with Winrar and 7Zip,with some different methods of compression, but with no results.

Comment: a jpg is already a compressed format. zip will gain no more. Music files are similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPEG images are already compressed so re-compressing an already compressed set of files won't decrease the size any further. The only solution you have is to separate the files into smaller batches (so smaller sets of images are transmitted) or re-compressing the JPEGs but losing some of the image quality.

Comment: mmm I was wondering if is it possible to create a big byte occurrences dictionary among the total of jpg files...